# Gerrit checkout of *all* unreviewed commits for master

Tags: gerrit

When using Gerrit Code Review - is it possible to checkout all unreviewed changes for the master branch in one go? I know it is possible to checkout a specific patch set (https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.2/intro-quick.html#_trying_out_the_change), but I would like to get *all* pending-review commits for the master branch.

Background: we currently aren't using Gerrit yet but we are going to. We have both automated and manual testing of the master branch and I would like to be able to keep on using that, *before* the review step, so I need to be able to checkout a branch with all pending-review commits.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your point. Are the unreviewed changes independent from each other, or each of them is built on top of another one?

Comment: That depends. For simplicity's sake let's say all devs would normally push to master, all changes are unrelated, and I am trying to get a branch with all these changes before any review has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Gerrit does not provide that feature. In fact, I am not sure if that is even possible without human interaction. If there are N independent unreviewed commits to master, there could be conflicts between them that would make it impossible to automatically build up a branch made of all N commits on top of master.